# Translation of papal decretum by Pius IX, "festum in honore Sanctissimi Cordis Jesu"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ecclesiastical-latin

I do not understand Latin at all (though I started learning it with very slow pace due to a lack of time...), but I would like to understand a Latin text.
Is there a way to get it translated or to ask someone who can help translate it?
It's some kind of church stuff from Vatican, but I cannot find an English or German version I could understand.
Is there a way to get that document translated?
(The Google translator just produces rubbish...)

It's quite some text (papal decretum) and I am not sure if it is a good idea to post it here and ask for help.

> Ex quo Clemens Papa XIII. festum in honorem Sanctissimi Cordis Jesu cum
>   Officio et Missa nonnullis Ecclesiis celebrare permisit, ad immensam Divini 
>   hujus Cordis charitatem recolendam tanto ubivis ardore fideles populi se
>   excitatos senserunt, ut nulla jam pene extet Dioecesis, quae privilegium 
>   ejusdem festi peragendi ab Apostolica Sede se non impetravisse laetetur.
>
> Id Rmi Galliarum Episcopi attendentes, ut festum fidelium animis adeo 
>   jucundum et in omni fere Catholico Orbe tam concordi pietate frequentatum ab 
>   universa prorsus Ecclesia amodo celebretur, humillima ea de re vota sua SSmo 
>   Domino Nostro Pio PP. IX. per subscriptum Cardinalem, cum nuper in Galliis 
>   Legati a Latere munere fungeretur, subjici curarunt. Occassionem namque sibi 
>   datam lubenti animo arripientes publicum ac solemne in persona Cardinalis 
>   Legati testimonium exhibendi suae erga Sedem Apostolicam venerationis, ipsum 
>   Parisiis commorantem ingenti numero convenerunt, intimamque ac plenissimam 
>   adhaesionem suam Romano Pontifici veluti Catholicae unitatis Centro et Jesu 
>   Cristi in terris Vicario professi, ut festum Sacratissimi Cordis Jesu ad 
>   universam extendere dignaretur Ecclesiam enixis precibus postulavere.

Best
Tom

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no good machine translator for Latin. If you're curious about a particular part of a translation, feel free to post it here--but this probably isn't the best place to look for a long translation.

Comment: I've now added approx. half of the text I would like to have translated. Probably it's too much for here, but it would be very helpful to have at least the first paragraph translated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm only an intermediate student of Latin, but I think I'll learn a lot by translating this. Here's what I came up with.

> In the time since Pope Clement XIII permitted several Churches to celebrate the Feast in
>   honor of the Most Holy Heart of Jesus together with its Office and Mass, the
>   faithful peoples everywhere have felt themselves awakened by such ardor to
>   renew their contemplation of the measureless love of this Divine Heart that
>   now hardly a Diocese exists which doesn't wish it had obtained from
>   the Apostolic See the privilege of performing the same feast.

(Literally, the last part is "hardly a Diocese exists which is glad not to have obtained…")

> The bishops of the French Religious of Mary Immaculate attending to this, in
>   order that a feast so agreeable to the souls of the faithful and observed in
>   such like-minded piety in almost all the Catholic World should be celebrated
>   straightforwardly hereafter by the whole Church, have arranged that their most humble
>   wishes on this matter be submitted to our Most Holy Lord Pope
>   Pius IX through the undersigned Cardinal, since he recently performed the
>   duties of the [Pope's chief legate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_legate#Legatus_a_latere) among the French.
>   Indeed the bishops, eagerly taking the opportunity to present public and
>   solemn testimony of their veneration toward the Apostolic See in the person
>   of the Cardinal Legate, met him lingering in Paris a great many times,
>   and having avowed their deep and fullest
>   adherence to the Roman Pontiff as the center of Catholic unity and
>   Jesus Christ's Vicar on Earth, requested by insistent prayers that the Feast of the
>   Most Sacred Heart of Jesus be deemed worthy to extend to the whole Church.

I'm confident that I have the gist of the meaning correct, but there are several places where I'm pretty sure I got some details wrong (especially *humillima ea de re vota sua, ingenti numero,* and *enixis precibus*). Hopefully someone more experienced will check my work and post corrections. **P.S.** Thanks to [@Rafael](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/469/rafael) for many corrections!

Comment: +1. My Ecclesiastical context contributions: fideles populi>faithful peoples (i.e., believers). Apostolic Seat>Apostolic See (the Vatican). Erga Sedem venerationis>of the veneration towards the See (the object of veneration is the Apostolic See). In persona Cardinalis Legati>In the peson of the Cardinal Legate. Pontifici veluti unitatis Centro et Christi Vicario>to the Pontiff as the center of unity and Vicar of Christ. That's what I can see right now

Comment: That's really great! I'm not sure if I could ask you to translate the rest of the text if I added it?

Comment: Thanks, @Rafael! Exactly the kind of knowledge I was hoping for. I'll put those in. Any correction for _ humillima ea de re vota sua?_

Comment: @TomS Sure, I'll give it a try. You don't need to type it in. I looked at the next paragraph [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Wo6ygtOyo6oC&pg=PA60) and it looks harder: more Catholic terminology and an even more complex sentence. It might take me a couple days to get to it. (It'll be a carrot while I'm working on something else.)

Comment: For *humillima, etc.*: "They have seen to it [curarunt] that their most humble wishes  [humillima vota sua] on this matter [ea de re] be submitted to the Pope, etc." A *votum* often simply means "wish."

Comment: @brianpck Thanks. "Wishes" makes much more sense. I just added it.

Comment: @cnread I have taken _Ex quo_ here to mean the temporal "since". I did some googling on "ex quo" and never found a fully satisfactory explanation, but from the rest of the sentence, I think it's got to mean "In the time since". Your explanation, that it abbreviates _Ex eo tempore quo,_ is the first explanation I've seen that makes sense! I'll update the translation to clarify.